# Generated Soap Client doesnt work in Elixir Distillery Release

Tags: soap, erlang, elixir, distillery, umbrella

I used the following library to generate a soap Client out of my wsdl-Files. 
https://github.com/bet365/soap

All works fine in my dev environment - i can successfully call the services.

The Problem:
When I build my Elixir Release by Distillery it seems not to work at all.
I get following back by the previous generated Client:

```
{:error, {:client, {:encoding_body, :error, :undef}}, ""}
```

I thought about a path problem regarding hrl-records (include folder) or generated client (src folder). All tries - no luck.
Moreover my application is an Umbrella-Application (maybe there is a problem..?)

Any help appreciated!

Comment: Check the list of applications to be started in `mix.exs`.

Comment: Wow, this time you are my hero! Thanks a lot! The soap library is based on the erlang "erlsom"-package. It has to be named in the list of "extra_applications" in mix.exs - it works, wuha!

Comment: Always welcome :)